# How to delete item from observable array?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have observable:

```
private events$: BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject<IEvent[]>([]);
```

I add data to this observer using:

```
 this.events$.next([{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]);
```

How to remove item from observable array from template??

```
<div *ngFor="let item in events | async">
   <span (click)="detele(item)">Delete</span>
</div>
```

I have tried to delete using this:

```
  public delete(event: IEvent): void {
    this.confirm
      .open({})
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        concatMap(() => this.eventService.delete(event))
      )
      .subscribe((updated) => this.eventService.next(updated));
  }
```

And service is:

```
  public delete(event: IEvent): Observable<any> {
    return this.eventsService
      .delete(event)
      .pipe(
        concatMap(() =>
          this.events$.pipe(
            map((events: IEvent[]) =>
              events.filter((e) => e.idEvent !== event.idEvent)
            )
          )
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: There's no way to delete items from Observables. However, there are operators in the RxJS library such as `filter` and `skip` that can filter/leave out whatever values you request from an Observable, but the values will still remain in the orginal `Observable`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but this could help in specific situations.

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete an item from the Observable, you have to emit a new value without the deleted item. A method in your component could look like this:

```
delete(item) {
  // Get current items from the BehaviorSubject.
  const currentItems = this.events$.getValue();
  // Use the id of the argument item to remove it from the currentItems.
  const itemsWithoutDeleted = currentItems.filter(({id}) => id !== item.id));
  // Emit the new array.
  this.events$.next(itemsWithoutDeleted);
}
```

Edit after you updated your post:

Your problem is that you don't update the events$ subject in your delete method, you could e.g. use tap here or use the subscribe method:

```
public delete(event: IEvent): void {
    this.confirm
      .open({})
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        concatMap(() => this.eventService.delete(event))
        // Use tap here to update the events$.
        tap((items) => {
          this.events$.next(items);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {});
  }
```

Comment: Okay, why my method does not work, see my updated question

Comment: Is it a mistake that the $ is missing here, so events instead of events$: <div *ngFor="let item in events | async">

Comment: Yes, thank you, could you comment my edition, I have added my sample

Comment: I edited my post too - you have to update your events$ subject.